# How to mock CreateRegistryKey using Fakes and Shims

Tags: c#, unit-testing, registry, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to mock up the Win32 Registry objects in order to isolate some of my code for unit testing. I am able to create the shims and they get called to execute my code just fine. However I am not sure how to make the CreateSubKey method work. It needs to return a new RegistryKey object pointing to the newly created key. But I am having trouble figuring out how to do that. Here is what I have:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimRegistryKey.AllInstances.CreateSubKeyStringRegistryKeyPermissionCheck = (key, newSubkey, permissionCheck) =>
    {
        return key;  // This returns the base, but I need a new one that adds the subkey...
    };
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel silly for not thinking of this before. Right after I posted, it hit me. I just need to make a new ShimRegistryKey.

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimRegistryKey.AllInstances.CreateSubKeyStringRegistryKeyPermissionCheck = (key, newSubKeyName, permissionCheck) =>
    {
        var newSubKey = new Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimRegistryKey();
        newSubKey.NameGet = () => Path.Combine(key.Name, newSubKeyName); // All I care about for now is the name of the new subkey
        return newSubKey; 
    };
}
```

Sometimes you just have to ask the question to see the answer. :-)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use Microsoft.Fakes to fake registry access. Strangely, I don't see the Registry related (or any other Shims) under Microsoft.Win32.Fakes . I only see some stubs which are not registry related. I am using .Net 4.0 System assembly & VS2017 Enterprise. Does anyone know what's wrong ?

Comment: Same problem here. After `Add Fakes Assembly` for `System` in `References`, I am still not able to use `Microsoft.Win32.Fakes.ShimRegistryKey`. It says `ShimRegistryKey` does not exist in the namespace of `Microsoft.Win32.Fakes`. I also check in `View in object browser`, cannot see `ShimRegistryKey` under both `System.4.0.0.0.Fakes` and `mscorlib.4.0.0.0.Fakes`.